# Prepare for segue If statement for selected cell?

Tags: ios

I have 2 custom cells and I want to pass data via prepare for segue if one is selected. The problem is I want to pass different data in the prepare for segue depending on the custom class the cell is.

Does anybody have any idea how I could do this?

Here's some pseudo code that may better explain what I'm trying to do.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

        GFPostShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        if(cell.Class == CustomCellClass1){
            CustomCellClass1 *cell = sender;
        } else {
           CustomCellClass2 *cell = sender;
        }

//perform actions

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the data in your tableView static or dynamic?

Comment: I'm using dynamic cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two custom cells, on Storyboard you can drag a different Segue for each one. Each segue has a different segueID.Then:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"]) {

         //...prepare destination view controller
        }
     else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondSegueSegue"]) {

        //...prepare destination view controller
        }


}
```

hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    GFPostShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];

    if ( [cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCellClass1 Class]] )
    {
        // cast cell to CustomCellClass1
    }
    else if ( [cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCellClass2 Class]] )
    {
        // cast cell to CustomCellClass2
    }
}
```

In view did appear (for when the user presses back and navigates back to this controller), deselect your cell:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```